# Regular curve $\gamma$ is closed if and only if its derivative $\gamma'$ is closed and $\int \gamma' \ dt = 0$.

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

> A regular arclength-parametrized curve $\gamma$ is closed if and only if its derivative $\gamma'$ is closed and $\int \gamma' \ dt = 0$.

I've found this in a paper and while of course
$$ \gamma(1) - \gamma(0) = \int_0^1 \gamma'(t) dt $$
holds, I'm wondering how I should obtain closedness of $\gamma'$?

Kind regards

Comment: Can you give us more context? Is it possible that in the paper a "closed curve" is defined as one having a periodic $C^1$-extension to $\mathbb R$? See Christian Blatter's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closedness of $\gamma'$ means that $\gamma'$ can be extended to a beautiful periodic $C^1$-function, s that the geometric picture is througout a nice $C^1$-curve, and does not have a corner or an infinite acceleration at $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)$.

A parametrization of half a lemniscate has $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)=(0,0)$, hence we have a closed curve, but $\gamma'(0)=(1,-1)$, $\gamma'(1)=(-1,-1)$.

Comment: So the "theorem" in the question is wrong.

Comment: @PaulFrost: NO. I hope I have explained in my answer why we need $\gamma'(0)=\gamma'(1)$ in order to obtain a closed curve which is $C^1$ regular even at the point where the parametrization is fishy.

Comment: I see, you define a regular curve to be one such that $\gamma'(0) = \gamma'(1)$. I understand that this makes sense, essentially you want to have a $C^1$-map $S^1 \to \mathbb R^n$. But usually (?) a regular curve is defined as a curve such that $\gamma'(t) \ne 0$ for all $t$. Perhaps you should clarify this point in your answer. By the way, what would be a regular non-closed curve in your sense? The theorem should apply to all regular curves.

Comment: I just had a look into your book "Analysis II" which I have kept since I was a student. In fact you define a regular curve as I remembered. I think the theorem should be reformulated as follows: A regular arclength-parametrized curve $\gamma$ is "$C^1$-closed" if and only if its derivative $\gamma'$ is closed and $\int \gamma' \ dt = 0$. Here "$C^1$-closed" means what we agree it should be.

Comment: @PaulFrost I think you're reformulation is what the author had in mind and makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

$\gamma(1) - \gamma(0) = \int_0^1 \gamma'(t) dt=0$

Implies that $\gamma$'s starting point and ending point are the same.

Comment: So why should $\gamma'$ be closed?